# Tensorflow gives "ValueError: Error when checking input"

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to solve the OpenAI gym Breakout-V0 with a Deep Q-Network Agent.
Every time when my agent reaches the point where:

- The replay_memory is filled enough to start training
- The copy_target_network interval is reached for the first time
- The target_network predicts for the fist time

Tensorflow throws following error:

```
Error when checking input: expected dense_3_input to have shape (33600,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

When I print the shape of the incoming `state` array just 1 line before i call the `predict(state)`, it confirms that the shape of `state` is `(33600,)`
Before this error is shown the model is able to `predict_on_batch()` inside the training loop with the exact same data (but batched)

Does anybody know how to solve this? I can gladly give more details and information if I'm missing any

Versions:
Python 3.8.7
TensorFlow 2.4.1
Gym 0.18.0

Comment: You are missing the samples dimension, one sample should be (1, 33600). This has been answered hundreds of times here.

Comment: You're right, my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dr.Snoopy said, it's a simple solution

Just had to do `np.reshape(state, (1, 33600))`